# When is a $C^1$-function $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ Lipschitz-continuous?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be continuously differentiable. I'm looking for a proof that there is an $M>0$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le M \| x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in A=[-1,1]^m \subset \mathbb R^m$. This proposition is familiar to me from the one dimensional $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ case, but I somehow can't wrap my head around this one.

I'm aware that in fact
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\| = \| \left(f_1(x)-f_1(y),...,f_m(x)-f_m(y) \right)\|$$
Where $f_i:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ are continuous functions, with a relevant domain of $A=[-1,1]^m$ which is compact. Therefore they're uniformly continuous there. I'm also aware that $\displaystyle\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_j}:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ are continuous functions.

I just can't seem to put it all together and I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Could you write down what you're trying to prove in the body of the question? As it is written now, it is not completely clear. It seems that you want to prove that any continuous function $f:[-1,1]^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is Lipschitz. Is that correct?

Comment: FredrikMeyer, he's asking about continuously differentiable functions. AdarHefer, try proving this for $n=1$ first (in much the same method one utilizes for $m=n=1$), then consider methods to generalize the result.

Comment: Thanks to the great edit by Christian Blatter I think it should all be clear now. Haha! *embarrassed*

Comment: Oh, I should also ask (playing devil's advocate): which norm are you using in $\mathbb{R}^m$,$\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: The standard norm: $\|x\| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{1/2}$ details, details. :)

Comment: Well try writing a solution using my first comment. If you stumble into any difficulties, let us know where.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the $n=1$ case and report back.

Comment: @JonathanY. So since the partial derivatives are bounded, the gradient's norm is bounded. Here's where I got to: (The n=1 case)
$|f(x)-f(y)| = |\langle \nabla f (y),x-y \rangle + o( \|x-y \|) | \le \|\nabla f(y)\| \|x-y\| + |o( \|x-y \|)| \le M\|x-y\|+ |o( \|x-y \|)|$

But how do I control the little o term?

Comment: The same way one does it in one variable: the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|_O$ denote the operator norm. We have that $Df_a$ varies continuous on $A$, so $\|Df_a\|_O$ is continuous on $A$, hence bounded as $A$ is compact, say by $M$. Then for any $x,y\in A$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\|f(x)-f(y)\| &=\left\|\int_0^1Df_{tx+(1-t)y}(x-y)dt\right\|\\
&\leq \int_0^1\|Df_{tx+(1-t)y}(x-y)\|dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1M\|x-y\|dt=M\|x-y\|
\end{align}$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm unfamiliar with intergration over vectors (I suppose that's on my next Calculus course). Do you have an idea that does not employ that technique?

Comment: AlexBecker, one needs also show the triangle inequality for 'vector integrals' (after, naturally, introducing the notation), using this approach.

Comment: @AdarHefer I'm giving it some thought, but I can't think of a way off-hand that avoids integration of vector functions. But integration of vector functions is not complicated; you just integrate component-wise.